# How to implement Loaders with dependency injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection

I am using dependency injection in my code to create make my code maintainable, I started filling my ArrayList with dummy data contained in a String, then we started filling it using a database, then I use a WEB API using JSON and using an AsyncTask.

```
 final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =  (ArrayList<Earthquake>) QueryUtils.extractEarthquakes();
 final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =  (ArrayList<Earthquake>) new EarthquakeController(new EarthquakesDB()).getListOfEarthquakes();
 final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =  (ArrayList<Earthquake>) new EarthquakeController(new EarthquakesJson()).getListOfEarthquakes();
```

In order to make it work with AsynkTask and the independency injection in the implemented method I called the execute.get() method.

Here is my interface

```
    public interface EarthquakeInterface {
       List<Earthquake> getEarthqueakes();
    }
```

Here is my Class that implements that interface

```
public class EarthquakesJson extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Earthquake>>implements EarthquakeInterface {
private static String URL_TOP_10_MOST_RECENT_EARTHQUEAKE_ABOVE_6 = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10";

@Override
public List<Earthquake> getEarthqueakes() {

        return  this.execute(URL_TOP_10_MOST_RECENT_EARTHQUEAKE_ABOVE_6).get();

    }
    ..........................
    ......................
    .......................

    }
```

Now I am reading that using Loaders is more efficient than using AsyncTask, but I can´t figure how to use Loaders with independency injection as I did with the Asynctask.

This is how I did it, but without using dependency injection although I tried.

```
public class EarthquakeLoaderJson extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Earthquake>> implements EarthquakeInterface {
private static String URL_TOP_10_MOST_RECENT_EARTHQUEAKE_ABOVE_6 = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10";

public EarthquakeLoaderJson(Context context){
     super(context);
}

@Override
public List<Earthquake> loadInBackground() {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    String line="";
    try {
        url = new URL(URL_TOP_10_MOST_RECENT_EARTHQUEAKE_ABOVE_6);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            json.append(line);
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(httpURLConnection!=null){
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }

    // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
    List<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();

    // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
    // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
    // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json.toString());
        JSONArray features = root.getJSONArray("features");

        for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject earthquake = features.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject properties = earthquake.getJSONObject("properties");
            double mag = properties.getDouble("mag");
            String place = properties.getString("place");
            long time = properties.getLong("time");
            String mapURL = properties.getString("url");
            earthquakes.add(new Earthquake(mag, place, time, mapURL));
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
        // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
        // with the message from the exception.
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }

    // Return the list of earthquakes
    return earthquakes;
}
//this is my method that I implement from the interface
@Override
public List<Earthquake> getEarthqueakes() {
    return null;
}
```

Here is the Fragment that needs the List. The code commented is the one that I couldn´t use once I changed the AsyncTask for Loaders.

```
public class ListMainFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Earthquake>> {


public ListMainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainlist, container, false);

    //final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =  (ArrayList<Earthquake>) QueryUtils.extractEarthquakes();
    //final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =  (ArrayList<Earthquake>) new EarthquakeController(new EarthquakeFromDB()).getListOfEarthquakes();
    //final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake =  (ArrayList<Earthquake>) new EarthquakeController(new EarthquakesJson()).getListOfEarthquakes();
    //I tried to use dependency injection
   // final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake = null;// (ArrayList<Earthquake>) new EarthquakeController(new EarthquakeLoaderJson(getContext())).getListOfEarthquakes();

    listView = (ListView)viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
   /* EarthquakeAdapter noteAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getActivity(), earthquake);
    listView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        //final String mensaje = notas.get(position).getMag();
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(earthquake.get(0).getMapURL()));
            Log.w("ListView", "Se despliega la siguente URL " + earthquake.get(0).getMapURL());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });*/
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this).forceLoad();
    return viewRoot;
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Earthquake>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new EarthquakeLoaderJson(getContext());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Earthquake>> loader, List<Earthquake> data) {
    final ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakeArrayList = (ArrayList<Earthquake>)data;
    EarthquakeAdapter earthquakeAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(getActivity(),earthquakeArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(earthquakeAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        //final String mensaje = notas.get(position).getMag();
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(earthquakeArrayList.get(0).getMapURL()));            
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Earthquake>> loader) {

}}
```